# Excessive line height on text when displaying on mobile email clients

Tags: html, css, outlook, gmail

I'm currently creating a signature design for Outlook desktop client and I've managed to get all looking well across the various platforms apart from some excessive white space between lines on mobile clients such as Outlook and GMail. It looks like the line height has been set to something like 150% despite being set to 100% along with margin and padding all set to zero.

```
<p style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:100%;font-size:9pt;">One line</p>
<p style="padding:0;margin:0;line-height:100%;font-size:9pt;">Two line</p>
```

Does anyone know of anyway round this issue? Decreasing the line height in anyway causing issues on desktop clients.

Comment: Try media query for the styling for small screens. Just change the values for line-height for smaller width screens.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately only inline css is supported in most email clients. I did give your suggestion ago though but unfortunately no luck.

Comment: Did you try using an absolute value instead of % values for your line-height? That should make it consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately px get converted to pt by Outlook its self and anything but % is stripped when it hits GMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like GMail and other mobile email clients such as Outlook Mobile don't render correctly when layout properties are set inline and/or set to zero. The below seemed to resolve my issue and for those clients which only render inline styling the spacing was as it should be anyway. I did notice that the last paragraph had some additional white space so hence the line break at the end which seemed to resolve this issue. So all lines look tight together as they do on the desktop. Hope this helps someone.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .sigRow { margin: 1px; font-size:9pt; font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;}
</style>
<p class="sigRow">One line</p>
<p class="sigRow">Two line</p>
<br>
```